# 2017 Bronze USACO Question 1 Runtime error python

Tags: python

I'm getting this runtime error for the 2017 USACO Bronze question 1. I am using python to solve it. Runtime errors are pretty common for me and I really have a hard time fixing them. Can someone help me figure out which part of my code is bad. I am very new to competitive programming (in fact this is the first USACO question I have solved) so please bear with me. Here is the problem http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=759

```
a_1 = input()
a_2 = input()
a_3 = input()

x = a_1.split()
b_1 = []
for i in x:
    j = int(i)
    b_1.append(j)
y = a_2.split()
b_2 = []
for i in y:
    j = int(i)
    b_2.append(j)
z = a_3.split()
t = []
for i in z:
    j = int(i)
    t.append(j)
A1 = (b_1[2] - b_1[0]) * (b_1[3] - b_1[1])
A2 = (b_2[2] - b_2[0]) * (b_2[3] - b_2[1])
if t[0] > b_1[2]:
    A1 -= 0
elif t[2] < b_1[0]:
    A1 -= 0
elif t[3] < b_1[1]:
    A1 -= 0
elif t[1] > b_1[3]:
    A1 -= 0
else:
    A1 -= ((max(b_1[0], t[0]) - (min(b_1[2], t[2]))) * (max(b_1[1], t[1]) - min(b_1[3], t[3])))
if t[0] > b_2[2]:
    A2 -= 0
elif t[2] < b_2[0]:
    A2 -= 0
elif t[3] < b_2[1]:
    A2 -= 0
elif t[1] > b_2[3]:
    A2 -= 0
else:
    A2 -= ((max(b_2[0], t[0]) - (min(b_2[2], t[2]))) * (max(b_2[1], t[1]) - min(b_2[3], t[3])))
print(A1+A2)
```

---

```
b_1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b_2 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
t = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
A1 = (b_1[2] - b_1[0]) * (b_1[3] - b_1[1])
A2 = (b_2[2] - b_2[0]) * (b_2[3] - b_2[1])
if (t[0] > b_1[2]) or (t[2] < b_1[0]) or (t[3] < b_1[1]) or (t[1] > b_1[3]):
    A1 -= 0
else:
    A1 -= ((max(b_1[0], t[0]) - (min(b_1[2], t[2]))) * (max(b_1[1], t[1]) - min(b_1[3], t[3])))
if (t[0] > b_2[2]) or (t[2] < b_2[0]) or (t[3] < b_2[1]) or (t[1] > b_2[3]):
    A2 -= 0
else:
    A2 -= ((max(b_2[0], t[0]) - (min(b_2[2], t[2]))) * (max(b_2[1], t[1]) - min(b_2[3], t[3])))
print(A1+A2)
```

This is my new code. I have made it more concise. Yet, I get this error:
[image]

Comment: "I'm getting this runtime error" - which error? I think you forgot to show it.

Comment: For the example input given for the problem, your code prints the correct result (17). I didn't get any runtime errors.

Comment: @kol the website has kept some limitations

Comment: I had a closer look at the code, and although it contains some of wierd ideas*, it seems correct. (* First, the input parser code is copy-pasted three times. Using a function would be cleaner. Second, instead of many if's and elif's, a single if could be used where the billboard area is decreased by the overlapping area.)

Comment: I think the runtime error occurred because the author accidentally provided wrong input (for example, 3 numbers instead of 4).

Comment: @kol so how would I combine the input codes into one. I usually have an issue for questions that ask for more than one input. Also, how is it the wrong input? There are only supposed to be 3 inputs and each input will have 4 characters which is what I have done right?

Comment: 1) You use the same code to convert a_1 to b_1, a_2 to b_2 and a_3 to t. This code can be put into a common place called a function. You can learn how a Python function is created here: https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/

Comment: 2) Yes, you read 3 input strings, that's OK. I meant when you typed in the input data (4 numbers 3 times) you could have made a typing error, which caused the runtime error. I think this is possible because your code works OK on correct input. ("3 inputs and each input will have 4 characters" -- you mean 4 *numbers*, separated by spaces, right?)

Comment: @kol I have made some edits to my code and put those edits in the OP. The new code is much much smaller and works all the same. I have even used the suggestions that you gave to modify my code. Yet, I get the same error. Could you please help fix it.

Comment: Ah, OK. So you get the error from the USACO the server... I think you need to modify your code: First, you should not use input() to get the input, you should read the billboard.in function instead. It's a text file with 3 lines in it. Second, you should not use print() to give the answer, you should write it into a text file called billboard.out. You can learn file handling in Python here: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/

Comment: I tested your code on the USACO server after changing input() and print() to file reading and writing and it passed all 10 tests :) But I wouldn't want to spoil your fun by copying the fixed code here as an answer. You are very close to success, so don't give up, add the file handling, and post the finished code here as an answer.

Comment: One more thing: you can eliminate the weird `A1 -= 0` branch from your code: `if x or y: do this else: do that` can be written as `if not (x or y): do that`.

Comment: Thanks I will try this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited a few days before posting this, to give you time solving the problem on your own, based on our discussion above. Nevertheless, I think it's worth showing the solution here as an answer to help others who might run into the same problem.

As I've already mentioned in my comments, your code works perfectly! The runtime error given by the USACO server was caused by a simple technical problem: you used `input()` to get the input data and `print()` to display the result, while the server wants you to *read an input file* and *save an output file* instead.

```py
# Load the input file
with open("billboard.in") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

# Calculate the solution (your code)
b1, b2, t = [[int(i) for i in line.split()] for line in lines]
A1 = (b1[2] - b1[0]) * (b1[3] - b1[1])
A2 = (b2[2] - b2[0]) * (b2[3] - b2[1])
if t[0] <= b1[2] and t[2] >= b1[0] and t[1] <= b1[3] and t[3] >= b1[1]:
    A1 -= ((max(b1[0], t[0]) - (min(b1[2], t[2]))) * (max(b1[1], t[1]) - min(b1[3], t[3])))
if t[0] <= b2[2] and t[2] >= b2[0] and t[1] <= b2[3] and t[3] >= b2[1]:
    A2 -= ((max(b2[0], t[0]) - (min(b2[2], t[2]))) * (max(b2[1], t[1]) - min(b2[3], t[3])))

# Save the result
with open("billboard.out", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(A1 + A2))
```

I tested this code and it passed all 10 tests on the USACO server.

Comment: Thanks for this kol. I did what you told me in the comments above and completed the problem perfectly, passing all 10 tests. Because of you I have now learnt a few things relating to file